# How to restart gdm in ubuntu without being logged out

Tags: ubuntu, xserver

How can I restart gdm or the xserver without logging out?
Sometimes, there is a freeze and I just need to redraw. It rarely happens but when it does. My only options are

1. /etc/init.d/gdm restart
2. ctrl+alt+backspace
3. switch to tty and restart

all those options force my session to end.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start at 3rd runlevel (or whichever is the multiuser without X one on Ubuntu) (set it in /etc/inittab) and then manually use `startx`, then when your xserver freezes, you only have to kill it, use `startx` again, but you don't have to log in, because you're already logged.

It still kills the session, but you don't have to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo pkill -9 ^gnome-shell` and `sudo killall -3 gnome-shell`

These are ones I use (not simultaneously though), hope they can be of help.

Answer (score 0):

run this command on ubuntu 22.04:

```
pkill -TERM gnome-shell
```